# How to implement continous messaging between servies?

Tags: android, service, real-time, message

I am writing an app where I read a sensor (or some other arbitrary continually changing piece of data) and I want to process it in multiple different ways at the same time, in many different services (for future expandability). How could I achieve it with only one service reading the sensors and then sharing the value with the other ones?

Comment: It depends would all these services be in the same process?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to use an event bus like otto

http://square.github.io/otto/

or event bus by green robot

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus